# Displaying progress view swift

Tags: swift

I am using `MRProgress` to provide an loading screen which works in my previous applications but implementing it in another ViewController would not just work and I do not know why.

```
var progressView: MRProgressOverlayView?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(" seconds to the end of the world")
        progressView = MRProgressOverlayView.showOverlayAdded(to: UIApplication.shared.windows.first!, title: "", mode: .indeterminate, animated: true)
}
```

any help would me appreciated .

Comment: Have you tried it in `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: yes. the same thing. now response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not showing because you are assigning it to wrong view with `UIApplication.shared.windows.first!` so replace it with `self.view` and your code will be:

```
progressView = MRProgressOverlayView.showOverlayAdded(to: self.view, title: "", mode: .indeterminate, animated: true)
```

**EDIT:**

Check out demo project [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=42058764768262372297)

And your result will be:

[image]

In demo project I have installed `pod 'MRProgress'` into the project and `ViewController.swift` file code will be:

```
import UIKit
import MRProgress

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var progressView: MRProgressOverlayView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        progressView = MRProgressOverlayView.showOverlayAdded(to: self.view, title: "", mode: .indeterminate, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: this displays the progress but does not animate. It does not rotate

Comment: It still does not work except I make the view controller main viewcontroller